# Why is MySQL "Writing to net" when connected to localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have MySQL configured locally on my server. No remote connections. However, it is 'Writing to net' -- any idea how I can figure out what is going on? I'm on CloudLinux 7 running MariaDB 10.1. Thanks!

`10583  abc localhost   xxx Query   0   Writing to net  SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' 0.000`

Comment: The server is writing a packet to the client. This state is called Writing to net prior to MySQL 5.7.8.

Comment: From [the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-thread-states.html) it appears to just be another way to say "sending to client". Here, PHP is the client. It doesn't necessarily mean that it is being sent over the network.

Comment: Is your issue just a security concern, or is there actually an error?

Comment: @Zanderwar Just wondering what the heck is going on, I've never seen this  before.

Comment: @Mike Ah, okay. Thanks!

Comment: It's good news :) Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that may run across this in the future -- this does NOT necessarily mean MYSQL is connecting externally. If you are considered about MYSQL connecting externally and you ONLY use MYSQL locally on your server, add `skip-networking- to`/etc/my.cnf` and restart MYSQL. That will prevent any external connections to MYSQL.